# Use of IFCONFIG and ARP SCAN to detect authenticity of devices

Tags: security, terminal, ifconfig

I am using Pop OS linux. I have typed in ifconfig into the terminal I get this output. Keep in mind I am also using vpn.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siUzt.png)

Then I tried arp scan for the first device, by inputting this line[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyRXy.png).
This is very unusual. I have searched throughout the but didnt seem to find this exact output. Could this thing be linked to hacking. I have searched for the mac address
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRsjc.png).
I am however using a thinkpad lenovo t470s model. But still something doesn't feel right. I have installed macchanger. and changed the maccaddress to another through this code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iZR8.png).
I have recently realised with the technology and resources at hand even an Iphone can be hacked. So I am going through extreme paranoia. Please Help